# How to reduce space between content in Flex layout, if content is placed in row direction?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**My questions are:**

1. How to reduce space between two rows?
2. How to reduce space between items, if number of items are less than privous row items?

**My xaml code:**

```
 <FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap" AlignItems="Start" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceAround"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
    <Image  Source="icon.png"/>
</FlexLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**What I want is:**

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this issue and eventually I found out the reason.

The reason why it will look like this is that the flex layout will **expand itself to the maximum** in default like what a Grid does, regardless of the children.

The spacing is based on the area left after allocating all the children. You got a lot of area left vertically so the space between rows got larger. If you use Xamarin.UWP or Xamarin.WPF and resize the app window you can see the space between rows is changing.

So, **HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"** is unnecessary.

Add **VerticalOptions="Start"** to the flex layout (Or sometimes if you wrap the flex layout inside another auto-expand control like **ScrollView**, then add this to the parent **ScrollView**) and the problem is solved, at least in my case.

When it comes to the third line, I just added **JustifyContent="Start" AlignItems="Start"**.

**Edit:**
Apply Margin property to each item, to get space between items.

Comment: This will resolve first issue but by applying this it will place all images next to each other without space between them in a row, I also want equal space between two images.

Comment: What if using "Margin" property for each item using Style? I just added a style under FlexLayout.Resources with a setter setting Margin to a value and everything works as I expected.

Comment: I had the flex layout in a scroll view, and adding **VerticalOptions="Start"** in the scroll view solved my problem. My flex layout was defined like this `<FlexLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Wrap="Wrap" Margin="10" Padding="0" JustifyContent="Center">`.

Comment: Adding VerticalOptions="Start" to the parent scrollview solved my problem too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
AlignContent="Start"
```

in FlexLayout.

By setting this property, the child elements are aligned without row space.
http://tecsack.com/xamarin-forms-flex-layout/

Comment: This will resolve first issue but by applying this it will place all images next to each other without space between them in a row, I also want equal space between two images. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used FlexLayout in Xamarin, but from my HTML/CSS days I would suggest that your issue is with **JustifyContent="SpaceAround"**. Try to change SpaceAround to **FlexStart**

Comment: by applying `JustifyContent="Start"` it removes space between two items and just place content starting from the screen, What I need is space + start position.

Comment: This will resolve first issue but by applying this it will place all images next to each other without space between them in a row, I also want equal space between two images.

Answer (score 0):

By default FlexLayout doesn't have RowSpacing or other parameter. What you need to do is define column nubers eg. 4, then dived your FlexLayout width by your column number and programmatically add elements to your FlexLayout. You can use OnSizeChanged event to do that and start adding child items to FlexLayout. Then you should set:

1. Direction: Row
2. Wrap: Wrap
3. FlowDirection: LeftToRight
4. JustifyContent: Start
5. AlignItems: Start

Some Example of code could be:

```
private void FlexGallery_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //imageDimension = Math.Round(FlexGallery.Width / 4) ..round it with  desired method
        foreach (var it in documents.OrderBy(a => a.DateCreated))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(it.Url) == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(it.Url) == ".jpg")
            {
                Image img = new Image
                {
                    HeightRequest = imageDimension,
                    WidthRequest = imageDimension,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5),
                    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(it.Url))
                };


                FlexGallery.Children.Add(img);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Where imageDimension is your FlexLayout divided by desired numbers of columns, and rounded with Math.Round.

Approach by adding it programmatically is different from approach where number of items is alerady known and defined in xaml.

This approach is only for items with scale factor 1:1 .

You should get something like this (this is tabbed view so ignore white line at center):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, but having one question that I'm using flex layout just b'cause my column number is not fixed and my content can take place by itself, as it supports phone and tablet, number of columns will change every time.Is there any way to solve this in above defined scenario?

Comment: Are you going to have always same item size inside FlexLayout, if so than yes. I can give you tips about it.

Comment: Ya, currently its having fix number of items inside Flex Layout.

Comment: What about size of items, are they always going to be scale 1:1 ?

Answer (score -1):

Might be irrelevant but I solved my issue by using a `StackLayout` or `Grid` instead where you can define the spacing width